# Unable to install google cloud on Ubuntu 18.04.TLS

Tags: apt, package-management, cloud

everybody!

I tried installing google cloud on my Ubuntu 18.04, but nothing happened. This is what I (lastly) did:

```
aleks@ThinkPad-T530:~$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
[sudo] password for aleks: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-crcmod
Suggested packages:
  google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python
  google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator google-cloud-sdk-bigtable-emulator
  google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator kubectl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  google-cloud-sdk python-crcmod
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 173 not upgraded.
Need to get 24,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 188 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python-crcmod amd64 1.7-2build4 [17,5 kB]
Get:2 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk/main amd64 google-cloud-sdk all 267.0.0-0 [24,4 MB]
Fetched 24,4 MB in 18s (1.390 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package python-crcmod.
(Reading database ... 145750 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-crcmod_1.7-2build4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-crcmod (1.7-2build4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package google-cloud-sdk.
Preparing to unpack .../google-cloud-sdk_267.0.0-0_all.deb ...
Unpacking google-cloud-sdk (267.0.0-0) ...
Setting up python-crcmod (1.7-2build4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up google-cloud-sdk (267.0.0-0) ...

aleks@ThinkPad-T530:~$ find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "google-clooud-sdk*" 

aleks@ThinkPad-T530:~$ gclound init

Command 'gclound' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gcloud' from snap google-cloud-sdk (266.0.0)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Comment: Actually, this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475281/1925356 Kind regards: Alex

Answer (score 1):

Reread your commands, and you'll notice that you have some typos:

`find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "google-clooud-sdk*"` <-- you typoed 'cloud' here.

`gclound init` <-- you typed `gclound` not `gcloud`.

My guess is that last one is the critical failure - you didn't type `gcloud` right.  Rewrite it to be `gcloud` and try again, making sure you spell it right.